# Binary JSON format that supports traversal

Tags: json, serialization, bson, json-serialization, cbor

Does anyone know of a serialisation format that:

1. Is binary and at least relatively compact,
2. Can store JSON-style data (*not* Protobuf, Thrift, etc.),
3. Supports traversal (i.e. you don't need to parse the entire document to read one part of it), and
4. Supports large files (e.g. 30 GB)?

I have looked at the following:

- CBOR - doesn't support traversal
- MessagePack - doesn't support traversal
- UBJSON - doesn't support traversal
- Smile - doesn't support traversal
- BSON - *does* support traversal! But the maximum document size is 2 GB.

BSON was so close but the maximum file size kills it for me. Are there any formats that would work? Obviously I can write my own, but there are sooooo many binary JSON formats, surely someone has made a decent one?

**Edit:** By "traversal" I mean the same thing that [the BSON authors mean](http://bsonspec.org/) - you should be able to find a given object without having to parse the entire file. Amazon calls this "sparse" or "shallow" reading.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "traversal" and "don't need to parse the entire document". Do you actually mean "random access"? All deserializable data formats will support access to data without keeping the entire thing as deserialized in memory, but they usually rely on reading the data from the start, because there is no random access index that tells the deserializer where things are. Please explain exactly what it is you're lookng for.

Comment: Clarified. "Random access" only applies to sequences of data, which JSON isn't, so it's not quite the right term but it is basically the right idea. And of course all formats allow you to discard data you have parsed - that's why I said you shouldn't need to *parse* the entire document.

Comment: No, but it's not entirely accurate either. Your mentioning in the answer you provided of the format that has length-prefixed binaries and I assume strings. In the sense of BSON type of things, it means that you might not have to parse the string to handle such things as escaped characters and so on, you could just skip the bytes directly, but then a binary encoding of such a string might've done that kind of handling already when it went from the text format to the binary.

Comment: In the sense that BSON supports traversal, then I'd say that all data **formats** supports traversal, inasmuch as they support full deserialization. The partial deserialization/memory handling would be a property of the deserialization code, and not of the format. In other words, the fact that CBOR doesn't support traversal would mean that the known libraries that support CBOR doesn't support traversal, but it should be possible to create such support. Might be more work than its worth though, I'd give you that.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure 2GB is the actual limit of BSON, but it is the limit of properties inside. So any single string can not be larger than 2GB, but I'm not sure that limit applies to the whole document, but then I don't use BSON for this kind of big data so I'm not sure I know all there is about this.

Comment: a) It's not about skipping strings (basically all binary JSON formats let you do this), it's about skipping entire *objects*. b) I think you still haven't understood what "traversal" means. You need to be able to skip parsing objects. There's no way to do that with CBOR even in theory. c) Yes it is a limit of the entire document (see the bit of the spec that says `int32 is the total number of bytes comprising the document.`).

Comment: b) That is entirely correct, and that was my point, that the word "traversal" does not have a clear definition, that is why I asked you to clarify in earlier comments what you actually mean by that word.

Comment: So with that definition of traversal, you can only use formats that have length prefixes for most complex types, otherwise you will have to parse their internal structure to know when they end.

Comment: Do you need the format to be compatible with anything at all? Can't you just invent something? You will first need to find an existing format that meets your criteria, and then you need to find a library for your programming language and/or runtime, and then that library must support this traversal mechanism instead of full deserialization. Seems like the odds are very low.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be TLV, e.g. a list of offsets would work too. And I can of course invent a format, but I'd rather not (look at how many binary JSON formats there are already!). I'm not sure why you think the odds are low of finding such a format given I've already found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one! [Amazon Ion](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/). [From the FAQ](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/why.html):

> Many reads are shallow or sparse, meaning that the application is focused on only a subset of the values in the stream, and that it can quickly determine if full materialization of a value is required.
>
> In the spirit of these principles, the Ion specification includes features that make Ion’s binary encoding more efficient to read than other schema-free formats. These features include length-prefixing of binary values and Ion’s use of symbol tables.

Brief notes on Ion:

- Seems to be relatively well designed.
- All values are TLV-encoded, which makes it traversable (yeay!)
- The length values aren't limited to 32 bits (yeay!)
- It has a slightly richer object model than JSON, e.g. it supports timestamps, binary data, type annotations and S-expressions (not sure why).
- It supports a symbol table so field names can be interned! That means it is probably *significantly* more compact than all of the other binary JSON formats.

It is not very popular. Libraries are available for only a few languages and I can't even find a command line tool that uses it. Still, it seems to be the only option if you want these features!

Edit:

In the end we went with SQLite which is pretty excellent. It doesn't really follow the JSON data model but it does let you do sparse reads very easily and it is very fast. Another possibility is DuckDB which is kind of a modern take on SQLite but less widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

For CBOR, I had similar requirements to you; not bounded by 30GB for me is resolved by infinite lazy lists and no single object being larger than 16MB (I just needed terabytes of "medium" sized chunks - your requirements may be different of course).

However, with the 'traversable' that's easy, there's a TAG which defines nested CBOR.  When decoding, you treat the tag as if it wasn't there. In this fashion you can have

```
{ "key1" : [cbor-tag] <<binary-cbor-subtree>>,
  "key2" : [cbor-tag] <<binary-cbor-subtree>>
}
```

In this fashion, you are "skipping over" the "values" as a single decode+seek, but if you just did a cbor-to-json, the parser WOULD have to decode the tagged binary as CBOR.. Thus you get the best of both worlds (BSON v.s. CBOR) being both streamable (via indefinite map len) and traversable.

Of course this requires specialized **encoders**, but at least the decoders should be trivial/standard.

For us, we happened to use specialized encoders/decoders that were aware of the tagged-binary value (because we needed to maintain a multi-GB map of potentially huge values).